# Listing available shared VPC in a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a host project with 2 VPCs , both of them aew shared with a service project that has no VPCs. in the console all works great, but I want to create automation for that. I am not able to list the VPCs in the service project. I am trying to use

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/aggregated/subnetworks/listUsable
```

from the documantation

> Retrieves an aggregated list of all usable subnetworks in the project. The list contains all of the subnetworks in the project and the subnetworks that were shared by a Shared VPC host project.

but I am getting empty result set
what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be relatively careful with the permissions and what user you authenticate as. You will only be able to see subnetworks where the calling user has the appropriate compute.subnetworks.* permissions.

If you're looking at the Cloud Console, you will be acting with your Google Account which most likely has owners or at least roles/compute.networkUser access.

Depending on how you authenticate your API calls, you are most likely using a service account. Ensure that this service account has the required roles as well.

For further debugging, you can also try using the gcloud CLI tool. It has a handy option: --log-http that will show you all HTTP calls done. This is often a great help when piecing together functionality in external code.

Comment: I am using the CLI and also enables the --log-http
the CLI and Console are working with the same permissions - of mine, and I am an owner

Answer (score 0):

I have looked on how GCP console is doing it
1. it query to see if there is host project
2. if there is host project - it send query to the host project to list the subnets